# Edges Joining Adjacent Vertices

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> ***Theorem 3 (Edges joining adjacent vertices; Exercise 2.15, p. 78)*** Consider the polyhedron $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid a_i'x\geq b_i, i = 1, \dots, m\}$. Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are distinct basic feasible solutions that satisfy $a_i'u = a_i'v = b_i$, $i = 1, \dots, n - 1$, and that the vectors $a_1, \dots, a_{n - 1}$ are linearly independent. (In particular, $u$ and $v$ are adjacent.) Let $L = \{\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v \mid 0\leq \lambda \leq 1\}$ be the segment that joins $u$ and $v$. Then $L = \{z \in P \mid a_i' z = b_i, i = 1, \dots, n - 1\}$.

One direction is pretty obvious.... Please help me out with the other direction...

Comment: Hint for one half of the proof: let $z\in L$ and use linearity to show that $z\in P$ and the equality constraints are satisfied.

Comment: That's very known.... Other way is the problem I'm facing...

Comment: @Anirudha.C.P. We’re you  able to solve this? I am struggling on this exercise as well. I was able to prove that if $z$ is in $L$ than  it is also in the other set. For the converse I have a starting point, that is $a_i z = a_i (\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v)$ but I am not able to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** How would you call a figure that results from an intersection of $n-1$ linearly independent constraints in an $n$-dimensional space? How is $L$ related to that figure? What did you learn about such shapes in Exercise 2.10? In particular, about their vertices.

**Hint 2:** If you have figured out what that figure is, what is its alternative representation? What I mean is that you are looking at the problem algebraically, but there is also a geometric way of looking at it (i.e., only in the context of vertices).

If you tried answering these questions but still got nowhere, you can look up the proof [here](https://math.solverer.com/library/dimitris_bertsimas/introduction_to_linear_optimization/exercise_2-15?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link).